# Java actionlistener between 2 class

Tags: java, swing, class, button

i have 2 class, in second class (DisplayResult) have `createAndShowGUI()` method

```
public static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Database Data");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    DisplayResult newContentPane = new DisplayResult();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(false);
}`
```

and in my main class(Mozijegy) a menu method and in menu method 3 button (a,b,c)
So my question is if i want to that i click on C button in mozijegy class then it show me the `createAndShowGUI()` frame (creatAndShowGUI in other class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to pass a reference to an instance of whatever class contains `createAndShowGUI()` to your `Mozijegy` instance. If that class is called `ClassX`:

```
 class Mozijegy { 
      ClassX classX;
      ...
      Mozigegy (ClassX classX) { //along with whatever other params you need 
         this.classX= classX;
         ...
      }
      ...
      buttonC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             classX.doWhenButtonCisClicked();
          }
       });
 }
```